# Python breaks for a certain amount

Tags: python

All,
I am not very good at explaining so i will let my comments do it!

```
#this script is to calculate some of the times table up to 24X24 and also miss some out
#Range of numbers to be calculated
numbers=range(1,25)
for i in numbers:
    for w in numbers:
        print(str(i)+"X"+str(w)+"="+str(i*w))
        #here i want to break randomly (skip some out) e.g. i could be doing the 12X1,12X2 and then 12X5 i have no limit of skips.
```

**Update**

Sorry if this is not clear i want it to break from the inner loop for a random amount of times

Comment: How do you decide which to miss out? Should there be a limit on how many you skip?

Comment: Randomly, sorry forgot to put that in. No there should not be.

Comment: In addition to @jonrsharpe question, do you want to break the inner loop or the main loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`random.random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random) to generate a floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0).

Then you can print the string only if the number is below a customizable threshold. For example in the code below I use `< 0.2` which means that the `if` part will only be executed the `20%` of the times:

```
from random import random

for i in range(1, 25):
    for w in range(1, 25):
        if (random() < 0.2):
            print('%dX%d=%d' % (i, w, i * w))
```

Comment: so to make it even more random could you instead of <0.2 could you possibly do random(0,1) instead?

Comment: Yes, but the result will be similar to `random() < 0.5` in fact if you select two random number `x` and `y` in the same interval, you have half the probability that `x < y` and half that `x >= y`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think he means for the right-hand side, like `random() < random()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to simplify the code, then [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to decide whether or not to skip each equation:

```
from itertools import product
import random

def random_equations(limit):
    for x, y in product(range(1, limit), repeat=2):
        if random.choice((True, False)):
            print("{0}x{1}={2}".format(x, y, x*y))
```

Demo usage:

```
>>> random_equations(5)
1x1=1
1x2=2
1x3=3
2x2=4
3x1=3
4x2=8
```

This will skip roughly half - you can either change the tuple you're choosing from (e.g. `((True, True, False))` would skip about one third) or adopt a numerical approach like [Enrico's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380788/3001761) to alter the proportion.

Comment: This is very nice i like it!

Comment: However i like code which is readable so i may go for @enrico.bacis instead sorry!

Comment: @BrianCox no problem, but what about my code do you find unreadable?

Comment: @BrianCox there's no need to apologise, but you really should get to grips with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) - concatenating strings with `+` is not generally recommended (as strings are immutable it's not very efficient), and you will see a lot of code that uses string formatting (either the version I've used, or the [C-style `%s`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)).